# HireFire error when moving from bamboo to cedar on Heroku: Connection Refused

Tags: heroku, delayed-job, hirefire

I'm migrating an app from 3.0/1.8.7/bamboo to 3.2/1.9.2/cedar. I'm getting the following error, which is preventing my HireFire to run my DelayedJobs.

Any idea what is wrong here?

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       [2013-01-29 03:57:48][HireFire] Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job detected!
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1194:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1194:in `new'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1194:in `connect'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:329:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:277:in `new_connection'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:287:in `checkout_new_connection'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:235:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `loop'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `block in checkout'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `checkout'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__3701001845916671889__prepare__1514527033144723608__callbacks'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/config/environment.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
       /tmp/build_60g64nyyf08f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to not involve hirefire at all. I had to add this to config/application.rb

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```